# Titanium Crash when App is on Foreground and receives a Push Notification message (IOS)

Tags: ios, titanium, push, appcelerator, aps

Im using custom server of aps with node js. When app is background push messages are received ok but when app is in foreground crashes in ios :

This error comes up:

> -[TiApp application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

My System vars:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11.4
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.3.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.1.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
```

StackTrace

```
 -[TiApp application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147d1d650
[ERROR] :  The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.
[ERROR] :  Reason:
[ERROR] :  -[TiApp application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147d1d650
[ERROR] :  Stack trace:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001813fedb0 <redacted> + 124
[ERROR] :  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180a63f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
[ERROR] :  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181405c4c <redacted> + 0
[ERROR] :  3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181402a1c <redacted> + 408
[ERROR] :  4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181300c5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
[ERROR] :  5  MyApp                            0x00000001002707f4 MyApp + 2017268
[ERROR] :  6   UIKit                               0x00000001868161a8 <redacted> + 2676
[ERROR] :  7   UIKit                               0x0000000186803f84 <redacted> + 136
[ERROR] :  8   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000182d9f7ac <redacted> + 36
[ERROR] :  9   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000182d9f618 <redacted> + 168
[ERROR] :  10  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000182d9f9c8 <redacted> + 56
[ERROR] :  11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001813b509c <redacted> + 24
[ERROR] :  12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001813b4b30 <redacted> + 540
[ERROR] :  13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001813b2830 <redacted> + 724
[ERROR] :  14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001812dcc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
[ERROR] :  15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000182bc4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
[ERROR] :  16  UIKit                               0x00000001865c6088 UIApplicationMain + 204
[ERROR] :  17  Cablecol                            0x0000000100089658 Cablecol + 22104
[ERROR] :  18  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000180e7a8b8 <redacted> + 4
[ERROR] :  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TiApp application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147d1d650'
[ERROR] :  *** First throw call stack:
[ERROR] :  (0x1813fedb0 0x180a63f80 0x181405c4c 0x181402a1c 0x181300c5c 0x1002707f4 0x1868161a8 0x186803f84 0x182d9f7ac 0x182d9f618 0x182d9f9c8 0x1813b509c 0x1813b4b30 0x1813b2830 0x1812dcc50 0x182bc4088 0x1865c6088 0x100089658 0x180e7a8b8)
[LiveView] Client disconnected
```

Any sugestions apreciated.

---

I'm answering to myself.

After trying without LiveView the application doesn't crash so it is a bug in liveview. I've already suggest an improvement in JIRA. I have verified this bug with 5.3.1.GA and 5.4.0.GA.

Comment: Can you show the data-format you are receiving as JSON in push payload?

Comment: I think you should try by disabling the LiveView as it is not recommended to use LiveView for Push Notifications.

Comment: Apreciate for you response Prashant Saini, i cant show you the payload because it crashes before i log the payload on the callback. It could be liveview, i'll test that and let's see what happens.

Comment: How come is that you are unable to see the payload and it crashes....if it's really the case then I believe nothing should be wrong with the payload..just something wrong with the environment....Payload format will help us to match your scenario with our working Push integrations. Hope to hear you soon with problem gone :)

Comment: please answer the question with an actual answer, not edit your question. Would be great if the answer would show up ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to myself.

After trying without LiveView the application doesn't crash so it is a bug in liveview. I've already suggest an improvement in JIRA. I have verified this bug with 5.3.1.GA and 5.4.0.GA.